# Reducing linear dependency among the columns of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a matrix whose columns are highly correlated, hence using this matrix in compressed sensing algorithms is not giving satisfactory results. So is there any way in which we can reduce the linear dependency between the columns of the matrix?

Snapshots of measurement vector 'y', sensing matrix'A' and required solution vector'x' are attached[image: measurement vector]

[image: Sensing matrix]
[image: Solution vector (nearly sparse)]

Comment: Would principal component analysis (“PCA”) do the trick?

Comment: How to use PCA for this?
Basically the columns are highly correlated hence they will be oriented along the single principal direction.

Comment: PCA functions on correlated data to de-correlate the data and give mutually orthogonal directions.

Comment: Thanks Dave, can you share link on where to read more about this.

Comment: Suppose I have ave a matrix 
A=[1 2;
     2 4]can the columns be decorrelated using PCA?

Comment: @AnuragDas please provide more details as to what you are doing, and sharing a small snapshot of data may help too. Is it your matrix square or rectangular? Are you allowed to drop some variables? What are your exact objectives?

Comment: Here's your link: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pca?tab=Votes.

Comment: @PsychometStats I am using compressed sensing to recover my sparse solution vector 'x' from a given sensing matrix 'A' which is rectangular and measurement vector 'y'. Since the columns of 'A' are highly co-related I want to know whether by any means I can reduce the linear dependancy between the columns such that compressive sensing algotithms can be applied to give satisfactory results.

Comment: @PsychometStats I have attaches snapshots to my answer.